# I need to generate A 32bit random and unique number in hex representation

Tags: java, int, hex

Following code is what I have done so far

```
    Random randomeNum =  new Random();
    int n = randomeNum.nextInt();
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(n));
```

Is this a correct way doing it?

Comment: Yes.This is correct.

Comment: Ok Thank you Ganesh

Comment: What you are doing is corrrect. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094823/java-how-to-generate-a-random-hexadecimal-value-within-specified-range-of-value

Comment: When we have 32 bit value like int then will the bits get changed if we convert it into hex?

Answer (score -1):

**You can use UUID to generate 32 bit random hex number.**

```
 UUID id=randomUUID();
```

Comment: isn't UUID a 128 bit value?

Comment: Yes, UUID represents 128 bit value that's why didn't use it.