# java- how to generate a 6 digit random hexadecimal value

Tags: java, android, random

I have a scenario in a Android app, where a random hexadecimal value has to be generated with 6 digits.  (The range of values can be hexadecimal or integer values).

What is the most efficient way to do this?
Do I have to generate a random decimal number, and then convert it to hexadecimal? Or
 can a value be directly generated?

Comment: Numbers are numbers. Just generate them within the needed range and do the conversion when you display them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094823/java-how-to-generate-a-random-hexadecimal-value-within-specified-range-of-value)

Comment: Combine [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681) with `Integer.toHexString(int)`

Comment: 6 digit hexademical number is 3 bytes. 3 bytes is 0..16777215 integer. Just generate integer in that range, and then show it as hex.

Comment: Random rnd = new Random();
int n = rnd.nextInt(999999);
Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n), 16);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    String zeros = "000000";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String s = Integer.toString(rnd.nextInt(0X1000000), 16);
    s = zeros.substring(s.length()) + s;
    System.out.println("s = " + s);
```

Comment: Also, just to make this more useful and complete, you should prepend `0x` and assign the result to a String. Icing on the cake would be to also show how to pad.

Comment: Use `String.format("%06x", rnd.nextInt(0x1000000))` to get zero-padding.

Comment: For secure application,we can go with SecureRandom class

Answer (score 6):

You can use hex literals in your program the same way as decimal literals. A hex literal is prefixed with `0x`. Your max value is `FFFFFF`, so in your program you can write

```
int maxValue = 0xFFFFFF;
```

Then you need to generate random numbers in that range. Use the `Random` class as you normally would.

```
Random r = new Random();
int myValue = r.nextInt(maxValue + 1);
```

Note the use of `maxValue + 1`, because the upper bound for `nextInt()` is exclusive.

The final step is to print out your hex value.

```
System.out.printf("%06X", myValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
int num = random.nextInt(0x1000000);
String formatted = String.format("%06x", num); 
System.out.println(formatted);
```

**Code Explain**

1. this random object use SecureRandom Class method. this class use for generate random number.

   ```
   SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
   ```
2. next int num object store 6 hexadecimal digit random number

   ```
   int num = random.nextInt(0x1000000);
   ```
3. then output num as 6 digit hexadecimal number

   ```
   String formatted = String.format("%06x", num);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

More generally:

```
int digits = 6;
String hex = String.format("%0" + digits + "x", new BigInteger(digits * 4, new SecureRandom()));
```